# C program doesn't open file passed as argument

Tags: c, arguments

I'm writing a program that takes 2 filenames as arguments, then it opens it and elaborates the data.
Problem is that it doesn't open the second file, for some reason.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fltr_file, *ig_file;

    ig_file = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    fltr_file = fopen(argv[3], "r");
}
```

`fltr_file` points to NULL (0x0) when I run the program. It takes `ig` and `fltr` as arguments, both files are present in the program's directory.

Comment: Oh, as a guess: `fopen(argv[2], "r"); fopen(argv[3], "r");` should be `fopen(argv[1], "r"); fopen(argv[2], "r");`

Comment: Your guess was right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `argv[0]` is the program name, the `argv[1]` is the first parameter.

If your program accepts only two arguments, you probably need indices 1 and 2:

```
ig_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
fltr_file = fopen(argv[2], "r");
```